# How to create clickable buttons on Windows CE emulator?

Tags: xml, windows-ce, emulation, device

Basically I have created a emulator for a phone like device. I have also created a skin with buttons on it. I was just wondering how to actually make the buttons do something i.e. in relation to the program however I would be more than happy for there just to be some indication on the skin that something has happened. I have tried using the msdn tutorials but I have had no success.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skin>
  <view titleBar="SalusSdk" displayWidth="480" displayHeight="272" displayPosX="147" displayPosY="103" displayDepth="16" mappingImage="Up.png" normalImage="DefaultSkin.png" downImage="Down.png">


   <button
          toolTip="Power"
          onPressAndHold="0x75"
          mappingColor="0x00FF00"
       />
       ...
        <button
          toolTip="Soft Key 1"
          onClick="0x3B"
          mappingColor="0x330033"
       />
       ...
       <button
         toolTip="Up"
         onPressAndHold="0x48"
         mappingColor="0x00FFCC"
         KeyEvent="Up"
       />
       <button
          toolTip="Down"
          onPressAndHold="0x50"
          mappingColor="0x0000FF"
          KeyEvent="Down"
       />

</view>
</skin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything out of sorts.  I'm looking back on one I did several years ago so give me some slack if the explanation is a little sketchy.

So the normalImage should just be a picture of your device.

Your mappingImage needs to contain only the areas colored in you want to be buttons, with each button colored in with a color matching the mappingColor value in the corresponding  element in the skin.xml file - below are a couple buttons from my skin.xml file.

The downImage should contain art just in the area around the buttons from your mappingImage with any effect your want - make it several shades darker for example.

Assuming you've configured your emulator to accept all your skin files, it should generate keystrokes that will be sent to the window with focus.  If you need to simulate a more global feature, such as opening a home screen, you'll have to hook the keyboard events in your app and respond accordingly - Code Project site has many examples of this for WM/CE.

```
  <button
        toolTip="Up Arrow"
        onClick="0x48"
        onPressAndHold="0x48"
        mappingColor="0x39b54a"
    /><button
        toolTip="Enter"
        onClick="0x1C"
        mappingColor="0x006600"
        KeyEvent="Return"
    />
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you for your help. One last thing though is how do I find the mapping colour? i.e. If I draw someone on paint and make the buttons different colours, how do I go about finding what the colours are.

Comment: Its fine I have found out how my bad.